# Unwanted delay highlighting UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, highlight, lag, ibaction

I have a custom UIButton connected to an IBAction. The action takes a long time to execute, and the button does not highlight in response to the user's touch until the whole action is completed. I would like the button to highlight right away to let the user know that it is doing something. Any idea how I can eliminate this lag? (without changing what the IBAction does)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to do the actual work on a thread. For example, you can use `dispatch_async`. Be careful about what will happen if another gesture occurs while the work is being done.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same issue. The action calls the way as you said, but I the way to fix highlighting for button:

1. Create subclass for `UIButton`
2. Override method `hitTest`:

   ```c
   -(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
       if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point))
       {
           self.imageView.image = [self imageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
           return self;
       }
       return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
   }
   ```

PS: I use separate images for normal and highlighted states, so I set `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` to **NO**.